# How to reduce begin Save state time in asp.net page loading

Tags: asp.net

I have A web page where the execution of code takes less time but begin save state and end render taking loads of time

The page contains a grid view with 3000+ records without paging

Some times the savestate time and end render are less and sometimes it takes more

```
aspx.page   Begin PreRenderComplete  0.714350792590854  0.000033
aspx.page   End PreRenderComplete    0.714360393532673  0.000010
aspx.page   Begin SaveState          10.0541238197049   9.339763
aspx.page   End SaveState            10.0542976298585   0.000174
aspx.page   Begin SaveStateComplete  10.0543191492109   0.000022
aspx.page   End SaveStateComplete    10.054334378291    0.000015
aspx.page   Begin Render             10.054350931639    0.000017
aspx.page   End Render              25.4521623141845    15.397811
```

Comment: You need to describe what your page does, the type and number of controls on it, etc.

Comment: I would suggest turning off ViewState for this grid.

Comment: IrsishChieftian: The page contains a grid control and a header and a footer thats it

Comment: How to turnoff viewstate only for grid. I am currently doing that at page level